# T(n) >= O(n^2) means T(n) should be greater than any function in the set O(n^) or just greater that one member in that set is okay

Tags: algorithm

If we say the running time of algorithm A is at least O(n^2) or T(n)>=O(n^2), does this mean that T(n) should be greater than any member of the set O(n^2) or just it is sufficient to be greater than at least one member of the set O(n^2)?
In other words does it mean for **any** member f(n) of O(n^2) T(n)>=f(n) or there should be **some** function f(n) in the set O(n^2) that T(n)>=f(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `T(n) >= O(n^2)`

If a very pedantic mathematician writes `T(n) >= O(n^2)` and they guarantee you that they did not make a mistake, then it means `T` is greater than at least one member of the set `O(n^2)`. Which is almost an empty statement. In most contexts you can guess that it was a mistake.

The only context in which I might expect such a statement not to be a mistake is an exercise where the teacher gives a function `T(n)` and asks the students "Which of the following statements are true? a) T(n) = O(n^2)   b) T(n) <= O(n^2)    c) T(n) >= O(n^2)". However I don't think that would be a very enlightening exercise.

If a computer scientist writes `T(n) >= O(n^2)`, it either means they made a typo, or they don't understand what `O(n^2)` means.

It is possible that that computer scientist meant `T(n) = Omega(n^2)` instead. But it's hard to guess what someone meant when they made a nonsensical statement.

### "`T(n)` is at least `O(n^2)`"

I would interpret the statement "`T(n)` is at least `O(n^2)`" to mean "`T(n) = O(n^2)`, but we can probably find a better bound". In other words, we already know that the algorithm does not run in more than `n^2`, and we suspect it actually runs in much less than `n^2`.

if I have got explicit reasons to believe the speaker is misusing words and `O()`, or if I know this speaker frequently makes ambiguous and misleading statements, or if I am a teacher and this statement was made by a student in class, then I would ask them to clarify what they meant exactly, as this mix of `at least` (which is often employed to speak about lower bounds) and `O()` (which explicitly means an upper bound) can be confusing.

Comment: Many thanks Stef for the great explanation!!! This is an exercise in CLRS, which says Explain why the statement "the running time of algorithm A is at least O(n^2)", is meaningless.

Comment: So how would you answer this exercise of CLRS, please?

Comment: If "at least" means ">=", then the statement is true for almost every function T, so it's meaningless. (I guess you could build a function T for which the statement is false, but this function would need to oscillate between positive and negative values and thus wouldn't describe the complexity of an algorithm). If "at least" is taken in the sense "T at least satisfies this property, but maybe we can find a stronger property" then formally it's equivalent to just "T(n) = O(n^2)", so the additional "at least" is meaningless in a formal way.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of `O`, no. Suppose algorithm A has complexity `n^2 / 2`. Hence, A is satisfying the lower bound, but for `f(n) = n^2`, `f(n) > T(n)` for `n > 1`.

Moreover, an equivalent definition for your statement for `T(n) >= O(n^2)` is `T(n) = \Omega(n^2)`.